# Opening displaying internal help (html) page

Tags: java

I can't seem to remember how to open and display an internal html help file (readable only).

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.2 and have created a desktop pane with a menubar. When the user selects help from the help menu I want it to display it an internal frame displaying the html help file that I have added to my resources.

Within the menuHelpHelpActionPerformed I'm calling myHelpFile(). MyHelpFile:

```
    initialUrl = "C:\\Users\\Mike\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\IwtTest2\\src\\iwt\\Resoruces\\iwtHelp.html";

    try{
        html = new JEditorPane(initialUrl);
        html.setEditable(false);
        html.addHyperlinkListener((HyperlinkListener) this);
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(html);
        getContentPane().add(html);

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>OOPS! no file: <br></br></html>" + ioe);
    }
```

All that happens when I select help it only shows the message dialog. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: From following an example from Core Java 2 advanced feature by Cay S. Horstmann & Gary Cornell (example 6-15) I was able to achieve what I wanted:

[image: animated gif showing solution]

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for posting a self-answer. Could you add some code or notes as to the nature of the example, so that other readers might benefit from it?

Comment: Hi @halfer thanks for the comments. I will share and show more detail on this when I have finished setting up a screen recorder and YouTube account. I will then share the link. But for now in brief, the example mentioned above creates a simple web browser with 2 buttons, a text field & editor pane. Using Netbeans 8.2, create a HyperlinkUpdate method, ActionPerformedEvent for the back button & within the properties for the editor pane add the URL required e.g. http://www.somewhere.com for a web page or File:/// someFile.htm to be displayed. Hope this helps

Comment: Sounds good. I should clarify that I am not personally looking for this information, just wondering what would be helpful to readers in the future.

Comment: Note also that while all help and information is welcomed here, links on their own (e.g. to  a YouTube video) tend to be deleted. Curators on Stack Overflow tend to aim for a minimum "substantiveness", i.e. at least some of the (text/image) description needs to be in the answer itself. If you need an animation, a GIF works here, and they tend to compress very well if you just use flat colour.

Comment: As requested animated gif attached

Comment: OK, thanks - great effort (+1). My only feedback is that none of that actually needed video/animation - it is either text or images, which are supported natively here. Moreover, all the text is trapped in images, which makes it incompatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engine scrapers, and it can't be edited. No matter though - all good learning for your next answer!